# Why is the Arduino code not receiving messages sent by PySerial code through serial ports (if they are even sent properly in the first place)?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to communicate between the Arduino (Uno) and a Python script to make a DC motor run. I am using a BTS7960 motor driver to control the DC Motor. The documentation for it is here if needed: [text](https://www.handsontec.com/dataspecs/module/BTS7960%20Motor%20Driver.pdf). I want the Python script (using PySerial) to send a message to the COM port and the Arduino to recognize it and act appropriately. However, the problem is, the Arduino expression, Serial.available() > 0 evaluates as false. My Arduino code:

```
int R_IS = 7;
int R_EN = 2;
int R_PWM = 3;
int L_IS = 4;
int L_EN = 5;
int L_PWM = 6;
int msg;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(R_IS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(R_EN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(R_PWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(L_IS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(L_EN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(L_PWM, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(R_IS, LOW);
  digitalWrite(L_IS, LOW);
  digitalWrite(R_EN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(L_EN, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.write("hi");
    msg = Serial.read();

    if (msg == "1") {
      for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i = i + 1) {  //clockwise rotation
        analogWrite(R_PWM, i);
        analogWrite(L_PWM, 0);
        delay(500);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i = i + 1) {  //counter clockwise rotation
        analogWrite(R_PWM, 0);
        analogWrite(L_PWM, i);
        delay(500);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Python code:

```
import serial
import time
serialInst = serial.Serial()
serialInst.port = "COM3"      
serialInst.baudrate = 9600
serialInst.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS


serialInst.open() 

time.sleep(2)

while True:
    serialInst.write(b'1')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Before, the TX pin was occupied and I changed it so that the TX and RX pins on the Arduino were not occupied, but it didn't change anything seemingly. I've made sure that nothing else was wrong, like the baudrate, COM port, the wiring, and the Arduino code itself will move the DC motor properly if I don't have the Serial.available if condition. I've tried doing Serial.write("text") before the Serial.available() condition in the Arduino code and it would work. The code was for the most part from different tutorials I used and I have no idea why it works for them and not for me.

Comment: you compare int with a pointer to s string literal (`msg == "1"`). but you send 1, receive 1, so compare it to 1 (`msg == 1`). (btw. it is not possible to sent 1 from Serial Monitor. only '1' so then you would compare msg to character '1' (`msg == '1'`))